# Index function occasionally giving #ref error when incorporating the randbetween function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

screenshoot with trace precedence
[image]

I have an unordered set of data in column A and want to chose a random member from that set, then use its value.
I am using the function =INDEX($A$2:$A$1001,RANDBETWEEN(2,1001),1) my data is numeric and on rows 2 to 1001 (there are no errors in the data).  Occasionally I get the #ref error appearing.  Does anyone know how to fix this or another way of extracting a random value from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDEX is returning the n-th value in the specified range (https://exceljet.net/functions/index-function), with values of n between 2-1001. There are only 1000 cells in the range, so it is producing the REF error on the occasions where RANDBETWEEN generates 1001 and thus asks INDEX to return the 1001th value which is beyond the end of the range.

Your issue is your range and RANDBETWEEN values are not matched for what you're trying to do - this can be fixed by changing either one - either RANDBETWEEN 1 and 1000; or making your range to index over include A1 rather than starting at A2.

I think you've likely confused the number though the range with the row number - which brings up an idea for a third solution of using INDIRECT instead of INDEX to reference the row number instead - INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(2;1001)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you both, I was to close to the problem to see the error.  I really appreciate the help of the site and will look to help others if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

This is not the only error in your formula - the second error is not so noticeable. It lies in the fact that you will never get the value of cell **A2** (in the screenshot it is **8.47**). For the [**INDEX() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) to work correctly, [**RANDBETWEEN()**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/randbetween-function-4cc7f0d1-87dc-4eb7-987f-a469ab381685) must return numbers from **1** to `<number of values>`,

in this case up to **1001-2+1=1000**.

Just change the formula to `=INDEX($A$2:$A$1001;RANDBETWEEN(1;1000);1)`

Or you can use the range $A$**1**:$A$1001 as the first parameter instead of $A$**2**:$A$1001

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$1001;RANDBETWEEN(2;1001);1)`